How to Use Script tag with custom attributes in the Layout.astro file
I'm using astro.build my static site.
I want to add a script with a custom attribute in the head tag of all the pages on my site. The script tag is as follows:
<script data-grow-initializer="">!(function(){window.growMe|| bla bla</script>

I added this script tag in the layout.astro file.
But after the site was built by Astro, the script tag didn't contain the attribute data-grow-initializer=""..
This attribute was expected by another program for correct functioning.
I'm using the astrowind theme.
Please help.

Instead of adding the script code directly in the layout.astro file, I followed the below steps and it is working now:

Created a separate component for the script
Added the component in the layout.astro file

Now the script is included in all the pages with the custom attributes.
